# segmentation fault happened in some compiler but not others

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have the following code. The compiler g++ in ubuntu12.04 tell me there is segmentation fault. But when I tried the same code in MingW g++ complier, it passes.

Any ideas?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class ListNode{
    public:
        ListNode *next;
        int val;
        ListNode(int x):val(x),next(NULL){};
    };

    int main(){
        ListNode *head;
        head->val=0;
        ListNode *p=head;


        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            p->next=new ListNode(i);
            p=p->next;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full segmentation fault? More info would allow us to help you, in case its a config issue or something else.

Comment: This shouldn't work at all... you never allocate head, it's a wild pointer.

Comment: `ListNode *head; head->val;`  head is not initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You are using head before allocating it. This is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). On the MinGW system it is pure "luck" that it isn't crashing, but it still invalid. You have to allocate head first:

```
ListNode *head;
head = new ListNode(0);

// do some stuff

// delete head;
```

Comment: That is really helpful, and all other answers. Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
ListNode *head;
    head->val=0;
```

is invalid. You did not allocate memory fot ListNode. So you can not write head->val=0;

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
head->val=0;
```

accesses a member variable val of an object head is supposed to point to, but head doesn't point to any object, yet.